# How can I merge Two tables in C#

Tags: c#

I have some problem in datatable merging. When i merge two tables like

```
            DataTable table1 = dataGridView3.DataSource as DataTable;
            DataTable table2 = dataGridView2.DataSource as DataTable;
            table2.Merge(table1);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table2;
```

this code output like that

```
        firstname             last name         fullname

        ABC                   CDE
        ABC                   CDE
                                                MMMM
                                                MMMM
```

---

```
        ABC                   CDE               MMMM
        ABC                   CDE               MMMM
```

but i want to show data like last two rows

Comment: Don't Edit Question. If you merge last two columns in first table it would look like one table.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you are looking to join the tables, not merge them. Merge is adding data from one data table to another with both having very similar schemas.

Comment: How are you filling the tables - do you use SQL or do you do it some other way?

Comment: i get the value for both datatables from two datagridviews..

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new datatable and add both of your datatables in the new datatable